# Best plot to represent categorical data

Tags: r, data-visualization, bar-chart, gplots

I have a dataset containing two time-points (T1, T2), two groups (Group A, Group B), and three types of emotional faces (happy, sad, neutral) and reaction time as the dependent variable. I have used a bar plot to represent the data using R. Are there any other graphs that can be used to represent this kind of data? A sample dataset is given below (for each participant, there are three emotion types and two time-points):

| participant | emotion | group | time | rt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | happy | groupA | t1 | 47.09 |
| AA | happy | groupA | t2 | 40.09 |
| AA | sad | groupA | t1 | 33.99 |
| AA | sad | groupA | t2 | 33.99 |
| AA | neutral | groupA | t1 | 104.97 |
| AA | neutral | groupA | t2 | 98.75 |
| AB | happy | groupB | t1 | 54.65 |
| AB | happy | groupB | t2 | 64.65 |
| AB | sad | groupB | t1 | 53.99 |
| AB | sad | groupB | t2 | 43.99 |
| AB | neutral | groupB | t1 | 24.97 |
| AB | neutral | groupB | t2 | 98.75 |

Answer (score 1):

An option could be representing your data using `geom_point` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = rt, color = emotion)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4, size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~participant)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Another option if you only want to represent your categorical data, you could use a [mosaic](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mosaic-plot-in-r/) plot like this:

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(~ participant + emotion + time, data = df)
```

[image]

Please note: this works good if you have different proportion between categorical variables.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Is it possible to plot a mosaic plot using the data mentioned here. I have around 30 participants in each group. If so, how do you add the fourth variable?

Comment: @Christina, yes you can just simply add the fourth variable in the function like ohters!

Answer (score 0):

You want to plot the information of four different variables.

One way could be to use a 3D plot (e.g., using points instead of bars) and add the fourth dimension by coloring the data points.
For instance: y-axis = rt, x-axis = time, z-axis = emotion, color = group.

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep("A", 6), rep ("B", 6)),
  emotion = rep(c("happy", "happy", "sad", "sad", "neutral", "neutral"), 2),
  time = rep(c("t1", "t2"), 6),
  rt = c(47.09, 40.09, 33.99, 33.99, 104.97, 98.75, 54.65, 64.65, 53.99, 43.99, 24.97, 98.75)
)

plot_ly(df, x = ~time, y = ~rt, z = ~emotion, color = ~group)
```

[image]

Depending on the data (and your personal preferences), the plot could appear "overcrowded"/ not too easy to read. If this is the case (in my view, here it is), you can reduce one dimension from the suggestion above (e.g., make it a 2D plot) and create two plots (e.g., three 2D plots; left plot entitled "positive", middle plot entitled "negative", right plot entitled "neutral")

```
library(ggplot)

df <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep("A", 6), rep ("B", 6)),
  emotion = rep(c("happy", "happy", "sad", "sad", "neutral", "neutral"), 2),
  time = rep(c("t1", "t2"), 6),
  rt = c(47.09, 40.09, 33.99, 33.99, 104.97, 98.75, 54.65, 64.65, 53.99, 43.99, 24.97, 98.75)
)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = rt, group = group, color = group)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~emotion)
```

[image]